# Solve the second-order equation $y''=(2y+3)(y')^2$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Solve the second-order equation $y''=(2y+3)(y')^2$

**My Trial**

Let $z=z(y):\;y'=z.$ Then,
\begin{align} y''=\dfrac{dz}{dx}=\dfrac{dz}{dy} \dfrac{dy}{dx}=z'\dfrac{dy}{dx}  .\end{align} 
So,

\begin{align} \dfrac{dz}{dx}=(2y+3)(z)^2\iff \dfrac{1}{z^2}\dfrac{dz}{dx}=(2y+3)\iff \dfrac{1}{z^2}dz=(2y+3)dx\end{align}

I'm stuck here as I am not sure of how to deal with the right-hand side, maybe I should treat it as partial integration or not. Can anyone provide a hint or help me continue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting
$$y''=z'\frac{dy}{dx}=zz'$$
(because $\frac{dy}{dx}=z$ by assumption)

Now, using the correct substitution, we get, 
$$\frac{dz}{dy}=(2y+3)z$$
which is a variable separable form.

Hope it help:)

Comment: Thanks Martund, I just saw that! Plus 1.

Answer (score 3):

If you write

$$\frac{(y')'}{y'}=(2y+3)y'$$ you can immediately integrate

$$\log y'=y^2+3y+C,$$

or

$$y'=Ce^{y^2+3y}.$$

This is a separable first-order equation, but with no closed-form solution.

Comment: Thanks! You gave a better answer but let me award the vote to the person with the smaller points.

Comment: There is a closed form for $x(y)$

Comment: @OmojolaMicheal: I really don't care about "points", I would be here anyway without them. You are deemed to accept the answer that was the more helpful/relevant to your question.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici: mh, it requires the error function, which is not "closed-form" by default. If one accepts the error function, one can accept the inverse error function as well (commonly found in the statistical tables).

Comment: I did not think about the inverse of it. Just the solution $x(y)$ ! Cheers.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici: I can't see this closed form… :-(

Comment: *complete the square*, ahah ! Cheers

Comment: Is there a way I can carry on using completing the square?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici: I think I see what you mean, but you get $x$ in terms of $p$, not in terms of $y$. I have checked with Alpha, the solution requires the error function or its inverse.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

You can make the problem simpler if you remember that
$$\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}=-\frac{ {\frac{d^2x}{dy^2}}} {\left(\frac{dx}{dy}\right)^3}$$ This would give
$$x''+(2 y+3) x'=0$$ Now, $p=x'$ which make things simple (separable), then $p$ and, at the price of a small change of variable, a very standard integral.

Answer (score 1):

$$y''=(2y+3)(y')^2$$
$$\frac{y''}{y'}=(2y+3)y'$$
$$\ln(y')=y^2+3y+\text{constant}$$
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=y'=c_1\exp(y^2+3y)$$
$$x=\frac{1}{c_1}\int\exp\big(-(y^2+3y)\big)dy$$
The integral cannot be expressed with a finite number of elementary functions. A closed form requires a special function, namely the erf function.
$$x=\frac{1}{c_1} \left(\text{erf}\left(y+\frac32\right)+c_2\right)$$
Thus the final result is :
$$\boxed{y(x)=-\frac23+\text{erf}^{-1}(c_1x-c_2)}$$
The erf$^{-1}(x)$ function is a standard function which is implemented in the symbolic math softwares. 
http://mathworld.wolfram.com/InverseErf.html